# How would I symbolize the following English sentence in logic?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

If only kryptonite kills me, then I am superman. [ k: kryptonite; K(x): x kills me;
S: I am superman ]

Would I need to use the universal quantifier somewhere here? And would I have to replace x with k?

Comment: Off the top of my head, the only formalization I can think of would require the equality predicate.

Answer (score 0):

> > If only kryptonite kills me, then I am superman. [ k: kryptonite; K(x): x kills me; S: I am superman ]
>
> Would I need to use the universal quantifier somewhere here? And would I have to replace x with k?

Well, you will need to express that "If anything is a thing that kills me, then it is kryptonite," aka "only kryptonite kills me."

That requires a quantifier, but not a replacement; rather an identification.